# Extract specific PHP strings in array based on keywords

Tags: php, arrays, string, foreach, strpos

i have registry data in text as below:

```
/Classes/CLSID/AppID,SZ,{0010890e-8789-413c-adbc-48f5b511b3af},
/Classes/CLSID/InProcServer32,KEY,,2011-10-14 00:00:33
/Classes/CLSID/InProcServer32/,EXPAND_SZ,%SystemRoot%\x5Csystem32\x5CSHELL32.dll,
/Classes/CLSID/InProcServer32/ThreadingModel,SZ,Apartment,
/Classes/CLSID/,KEY,,2011-10-14 00:00:36
/Classes/CLSID/,SZ,,
/Classes/CLSID/InprocServer32,KEY,,2011-10-14 00:00:36
/Classes/CLSID/InprocServer32/,C:\x5CWINDOWS\x5Csystem32\x5Cmstime.dll,
```

then i do $registry = explode "\n" and create list of arrays below:

```
var_dump($registry);

[1]=> string(121) "/Classes/CLSID/AppID,SZ,{0010890e-8789-413c-adbc-48f5b511b3af}," 
[2]=> string(139) "/Classes/CLSID/InProcServer32,KEY,,2011-10-14 00:00:33" 
[3]=> string(89) "/Classes/CLSID/InProcServer32/,EXPAND_SZ,%SystemRoot%\x5Csystem32\x5CSHELL32.dll," 
[4]=> string(103) "/Classes/CLSID/InProcServer32/ThreadingModel,SZ,Apartment," 
[5]=> string(103) "/Classes/CLSID/,KEY,,2011-10-14 00:00:36"
[6]=> string(121) "/Classes/CLSID/,SZ,," 
[7]=> string(139) "/Classes/CLSID/InprocServer32,KEY,,2011-10-14 00:00:36" 
[8]=> string(89) "/Classes/CLSID/InprocServer32/,C:\x5CWINDOWS\x5Csystem32\x5Cmstime.dll,"
```

i also have keywords in array form

```
var_dump($keywords);

[1]=> string(12) "Math.dll"
[2]=> string(12) "System.dll"
[3]=> string(12) "inetc.dll"
[4]=> string(12) "time.dll"
```

i want to show lines in $registry that consist string in $keywords, so i create 1 function below:

```
    function separate($line) {
      global $keywords;
      foreach ($keywords as $data_filter) {
          if (strpos($line, $data_filter) !== false) {
        return true;
          }
      }
      return false;
    }

$separate = array_filter($registry, 'separate');
```

since in $keywords consists "time.dll" so the codes produce result as below:

```
var_dump($seperate);

[1]=> string(89) "/Classes/CLSID/InprocServer32/,C:\x5CWINDOWS\x5Csystem32\x5Cmstime.dll,"
```

in my case the result is not true because, mstime.dll != time.dll and the information is improper.

the output should be empty.

lets say i replace the "\x5C" as space, there is any function that can do the job? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

To go along with the array_filter way you have to do things:

```
function separate($line) {
    global $keywords;
    foreach ($keywords as $data_filter) {
        // '.' means any character in regex, while '\.' means literal period
        $data_filter = str_replace('.', '\.', $data_filter);
        if (preg_match("/\\x5C{$data_filter}/", $line)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This would return false for

```
/Classes/CLSID/InprocServer32/,C:\x5CWINDOWS\x5Csystem32\x5Cmstime.dll,
```

but true for

```
/Classes/CLSID/InprocServer32/,C:\x5CWINDOWS\x5Csystem32\x5Ctime.dll,
```

If you're not familiar with [Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), they are awesome and powerful. You can customize mine as needed to suit your situation.